# how can we add advertise in android application internally and broadcast to everyone

Tags: android, ads

I Have Created a android application. In this application i have add a page for drivers/car wanted advertisement.
This Page Advertise button on the page on which i want to add functionality.
This page is mainly for the members of the application to advertise internal.If member looking for driver they can advertise here.It can be broadcast to everyone or publish in one page.